# How Do I Get Form Values on Refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to be able to get the values of a form (specifically, which value is selected in a dropdown for each item in a list of items).

When the user refreshes the page, the model state doesn't update, yet the values in the form persist. For example, if I select something from a dropdown and then press refresh, that value is still selected. Is there any way to get those values that persist in the form, but do not show up in the model, as they are not posted to the server normally?

This is in a `<select>` with an Id of Fees_0__EffectiveTerm, and a name of Fees[0].EffectiveTerm. I've tried to use

```
for (var i = 0; i < model.Fees.Count; i++) {
    Request.Form["Fees["+i+"].EffectiveTerm"]
    Request.Form["Fees_"+i+"__EffectiveTerm"]
    ViewData["Fees[" + i + "].EffectiveTerm"]
    ViewData["Fees_" + i + "__EffectiveTerm"]
}
```

and none of those return the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wish for your form values to be kept between page refreshes then simply add the following attribute to your form controls

```
autocomplete=off
```

If the current action is a GET request then simply performing a refresh (F5) of your page will not send any data through to the server for it to be saved in your model. What you're seeing is the browser aggressively caching your content on the client side.

Comment: If this solved your issue, could you please mark it as the solution? Much appreciated!